# How to set text in center horizontal of action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-imageview

I want to set Text in center horizontal of action bar and I want to place button like the image below.

How can I set text in center horizontal of action bar?

Can I change the icon of action bar instead of mine?

[image]

Comment: You really don't want to do this. That above design shouldn't be used on Android at all. That might be use on some other platform, but on Android The title stays left, and there is only the icon (with optional up functionality) left of the title. The icons also doesn't match at all the style guides (http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html). If you put an app out there looking like that, i can assure you, you will get a lot of bad rankings!

Answer (score 0):

Use your own XML layout for the Action Bar. Set the text in center using any layout you want.

In your `oncreate` method:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Comment: I use api 15. when I place your code it doesn't have `getSupportActionBar()`. It's has only `getActionBar()`. Anyway How can I set like picture above?